# Laravel Custom Guard for Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-5.6

I'am trying to build an apps with two types of user.
The problem is the custom guard is not working when i use passport driver, so i cant authenticate to another table

this will work to authenticate multiple type of user:

```
Auth::guard('web')->attempt(........);    //guard with session driver
```

this won't work:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(........);    //guard with passport driver
```

this work but i cant authenticate another type of user:

```
Auth::attempt(........);    //guard with passport driver
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally get it done from [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161)